# Why is AM XML file re-shuffling when adding a VO to it?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Oracle ADF and JDeveloper 12c (12.2.1.12.54). I added a new VO to an existing AM via the JDeveloper GUI. Usually, when I do that, it just adds three new lines to the source XML of the AM, stating the local VO name and package name. Something like this:

```
<ViewUsage
     Name="TestVO1"
     ViewObjectName="com.user.view.TestVO"/>
```

When I added the new VO, other than adding these three lines, it was also re-shuffling the rest of the XML, like moving some methods from line 400 to 600 and vice-versa. Not sure why it is doing that. Also, the line count reduces from 1200 to 800.

I am new to the framework and the IDE and cannot post the actual code. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us your exact JDev version, please?

Does the reshuffle matter? Do you see any problem with that?

Comment: @TimoHahn Added the JDeveloper version to the question. There is a method that has the same signature in the XML multiple times (11 duplicates). So the JDeveloper is removing all those duplicates when I am adding the VO. It is not wrong, but out of scope for my current task i.e., the addition of a new VO.

Comment: So, the app is working correctly after removing the duplicates. I don't get your point. JDev cleaned up stuff that should not be there in the first place.